# Create multiple results from single row joining either 2 or 3 tables based off conditional of table1 results?

Tags: mysql, sql, faircom-db-sql

First let me say that yes, this is a horrible way to have stored data, second, it isn't my fault :) I am trying to integrate with a 3rd party database to extract info which is stored in 3 tables, which really should have been in two AND stored where table 2 had a many to one relationship. Since that isn't the case, I have a puzzle to share.

Table one contains rows in which multiple values can be stored. Each row has `codeid1`-`codeid20`. These columns may contain a value, or a 0 (they are never `null`). They also have a corresponding `codetype1`-`codetype20` which will be either 0 or 1.

If `codetype1` is equal to 0, we go to table 2 and select `description` from the matching `table1.codeid1=table2.id`. If `codetype1` equals 1, we now have to look at table3 and find where `table1.codeid1=table3.id` and then match `table3.table2id=table2.id` and return the description.

Here is the data structure:

```
table1
codeid1,codeid2,codeid3,...codeid20 ... codetype1,codetype2,codetype3,.....codetype20
18      13      1          33           0         0         1              1
13      21      45         0            0         1         0              0


table2
id,    description
13    Item 13 Description
15    Item 15 Description
17    Item 17 Description
18    Item 18 Description
21    Item 21 Description
28    Item 28 Description
45    Item 45 Description

table3
id,  table2id
1    15
33   17
21   28
```

The results I would be looking for would look like this:

```
rowid, description
1      Item 18 Description
1      Item 13 Description
1      Item 15 Description
1      Item 17 Description
2      Item 13 Description
2      Item 28 Description
2      Item 45 Description
```

I got started working with someone last night, but I had missed part of the complexity of my situation in not integrating table3. Like I said, fun puzzle... This gives me the relationship between the first 2 tables, but I am unsure how I can work in a 3rd table.

```
SELECT table1.rowid, table2.description
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 
ON table2.id=table1.codeie1
OR table2.id=table1.codeie2
...
```

The database is a Faircom C-Tree DB over an ODBC connection, which is generally compatible with Mysql statements including UNION, WITH, INTERSECT, EXISTS, JOIN... There is no PIVOT function.

https://docs.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/sqlref.pdf

Comment: Wow!  There isn't even a tag for your database.

Comment: hehehehehe that reaction of @GordonLinoff :D priceless!!!

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I tried to add it but it wouldn't let me because I don't have the reputation for it. If you could create that tag, it may gain some popularity, which might make it easier for people to find help on it. It seems to be a Enterprise only DB for Fortune 500 companies, but without all the nice workings of the free Mysql.

Comment: Buy a decent pair of running shoes. Put them on. And run.

Comment: @Alan . . . I invented the tag.  I don't think I've done that before.  It didn't ask me for documentation or a description.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will work with `or` rather than `in`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from table1 as t1
              where t2.id = t1.codeid1 or
                    t2.id = t2.codeid2 or
                    . . .
             );
```

Comment: I get the error: `Execute Query Failed with an unknown error... Syntax error`. That was even simplifying it to a single match like this: `select t2.description,  t2.id from table2 as t2 where exists (select 1 from table1 as t1 where t2.id = t1.codeid1);`

Comment: I updated my original question with a working query using an inner join, but now how can I use the `codetype` to work in a 3rd table?

Comment: @Alan . . . A new question should be asked as a new question.  Not by modifying an existing question and invalidating any answers.

Comment: Thank you, I got it half way working but had a major headache when installing the Faircom tools hijacked my ODBC connection to the DB and halted actual testing outside the Faircom SQL Browser. I will post again on Monday if I need more help, and will post my solution after I sanitize it.