# Get DataTable Value from Adjacent Cell without ForEach loop?

Tags: c#, sql, foreach, faircom-db-sql

I am working my way around this problem: [Create multiple results from single row joining either 2 or 3 tables based off conditional of table1 results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464936/create-multiple-results-from-single-row-joining-either-2-or-3-tables-based-off-c) and while I wish I could take `Strawberry's` advice, I can't, so I am trying now to do more in C# rather than through the DB, but also trying to be smart about how much CPU I utilize.

For scale, table1 may have 50,000 records which have those 20 `codetype` fields which have to be evaluated before they can be matched to table2, which has about 2,000 rows, or table3, which could have 200,000 rows. To avoid hammering the DB, I am going to store what is possible in memory, limit results by date as much as possible, but I want to avoid 2,000 foreach loops per 20 codetype matches.

To start off, I am getting the results I need from table2 and loading them into a C# DataTable stored as the variable named `descriptionLookup`:

```
id,    description
13    Item 13 Description
15    Item 15 Description
17    Item 17 Description
18    Item 18 Description
21    Item 21 Description
28    Item 28 Description
45    Item 45 Description
```

And table3 as `lookupTable`:

```
id,  table2id
1    15
33   17
21   28
```

doing a simple (not showing all surrounding code, just relevant):

```
var rawData = new DataTable();
using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand("SELECT id, description from table2", conn))
{
    using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        rawData.Load(reader);
        conn.Close();
        return rawData;
    }

}
```

I then have that assigned to a variable that called the function. Now I have to deal with table1:

```
codeid1,codeid2,codeid3,...codeid20 ... codetype1,codetype2,codetype3,.....codetype20
18      13      1          33           0         0         1              1
13      21      45         0            0         1         0              0
```

Using a foreach row, I need to evaluate each codetype column for a 1 or a 0. When codetype=1 I need to grab the associated codeid, and then do a lookup from the data I am holding in memory as `descriptionLookup` to see what the table2id is that matches the `id` in `lookuptable` and then use that to lookup the description of the associated field in table2.

If codetype is 0, I just need to match `codeid` with the associated description field in table2.

I am looking at how to lay this out, and all I can think of is:

```
DataTable descriptionLookup= DB.ExecuteQuery("SELECT id, description from table2");
DataTable lookupTable= DB.ExecuteQuery("SELECT id, table2id from table3");
DataTable mainData= DB.ExecuteQuery("SELECT * from from table1");

foreach (var row in mainData)
{
    var manDataId = row.GetColumn("id");
    var subroutine = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (var index = 1; index < 20; index++)
    {
        string description;
        if (row.GetColumn("codetype" + index) == "1")
        {
            int idLookup = row.GetColumn(["codeid" +index]);
            foreach (var row2 in lookupTable)
            {
                if (row3.GetColumn("id") == idLookup)
                {
                    descriptionId = row3.GetColumn("table2id");
                    foreach (var row2 in descriptionLookup)
                    {
                        if (row.GetColumn("id") == descriptionId)
                        {
                        description = row2.GetColumn("description").ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }elseif (row.GetColumn("codetype" + index) == "0")
        {
            descriptionId = row.GetColumn(["codeid" +index]);
            foreach (var row2 in descriptionLookup)
            {
                if (row.GetColumn("id") == descriptionId)
                {
                description = row2.GetColumn("description").ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        subroutine.Add(manDataId.ToString(), description.ToString());
    }

ArrayData.Add(subroutine);
}
```

I haven't tried running the above code, so there is probably a problem or two in there, but it gets the point across of looping through thousands of records using `foreach (var row3 in idLookup)`. The alternative seems to be making a DB query, but that seems more intensive than just looping through what is in memory, but it seems like there is a better way that I am missing on how to get the `id` or `table2id` without using a foreach.

To make this the longest looking question in history :) Here is my SQL that I have so far:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.field1, table1.field2,
table2.description, fee.amt as fee FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
ON table2.id = table1.codeid1
OR table2.id = table1.codeid2
OR table2.id = table1.codeid3
OR table2.id = table1.codeid4
OR table2.id = table1.codeid5
OR table2.id = table1.codeid6
OR table2.id = table1.codeid7
OR table2.id = table1.codeid8
OR table2.id = table1.codeid9
OR table2.id = table1.codeid10
OR table2.id = table1.codeid11
OR table2.id = table1.codeid12
OR table2.id = table1.codeid13
OR table2.id = table1.codeid14
OR table2.id = table1.codeid15
OR table2.id = table1.codeid16
OR table2.id = table1.codeid17
OR table2.id = table1.codeid18
OR table2.id = table1.codeid19
OR table2.id = table1.codeid20
INNER JOIN fee ON table2.id = fee.id
WHERE table1.codetype1 = 0
AND table1.codetype2 = 0
AND table1.codetype3 = 0
AND table1.codetype4 = 0
AND table1.codetype5 = 0
AND table1.codetype6 = 0
AND table1.codetype7 = 0
AND table1.codetype8 = 0
AND table1.codetype9 = 0
AND table1.codetype10 = 0
AND table1.codetype11 = 0
AND table1.codetype12 = 0
AND table1.codetype13 = 0
AND table1.codetype14 = 0
AND table1.codetype15 = 0
AND table1.codetype16 = 0
AND table1.codetype17 = 0
AND table1.codetype18 = 0
AND table1.codetype19 = 0
AND table1.codetype20 = 0
```

This works great as long as there isn't any of the `codetype` that have a 1, otherwise that record will be skipped. There will likely not be a single row where all `codeid / codetype` are filled out, nor will there ever be a case where `codetype` will be 1 across the board to match the inverse of this query.

Comment: Honestly, I would leave most of this work at the DB level, and not C#.  It seems like you're taking the opposite approach.  Let the DB do what it's meant to do.  I would think that you'd be able to design a DB query that achieves most, if not all, of your objectives here.  Can you explain why that's not the case?

Comment: The issue I had was that when I did the `INNER JOIN` I used 20 `OR` statements to see if any of the `codetype` fields were 0, but that meant it wasn't filtering to the ones that were =1 correctly. I don't know how to set up a SQL query that can do the logic I described above, or if it is even possible to conditionally join a table, only if some value is equal to 1. That was why I resorted to C# logic.

Comment: It should be possible.  While I'm not familiar with your particular flavor of SQL, it's most certainly possible in the various flavors I am familiar with.  There are various ways to do it (multiple INNER JOIN on the same table, join on temp table (some DB don't allow this), UNION, etc)

Comment: Perhaps edit your question and add your best attempt at the DB query approach?

Comment: do a google search on how to construct a Sql Query with Joins I think this would be your simplest and most efficient approach to take in my opinion

Comment: @devlincarnate I added what I have, I just don't know how to manage that subquery where I have to join a 3rd table if `codetype3=1` and only associate the returned description with `codeid3`.

Comment: @MethodMan I have looked into the join, but we really just have a bad group of starting data to work with, which we have no choice about.

Comment: Oh man that looks gross.  Is it at all possible that you migrate the 20 codeId fields into another table.  A lookup table with only 2 or 3 (maybe 4 cause an identity column couldn't hurt) columns would do the trick.  TableName, TableId, and CodeId.  If not, trying to determine if 1 id matches any of 20, AND all of another set of 20  = 0 is going to have lots of repetition, much like the query you posted.

Comment: I don't have write privileges to the DB :(

Comment: Do you have sufficient privileges to create temp tables?  if not, does your dbms support table variables?  As others have said, this work sounds like it is well-suited to the database, and if you can make use of temp tables or table variables, that will help streamline things (and also help with readability/maintainability).  If you can use these things, then I'd use them to create join tables, then use those to build your final result set.  That might also work out to be more efficient than a single massive query.

Comment: Does your database support UNION or UNION ALL ?

Comment: It does, Devlin, I got it figured out today how to do a "conditional left join". I need to clean it up and post it tomorrow with a working example :)